# Is there an endConversation event to listen for in the Bot Framework?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm aware of endConversation() and endConversationAction, however, I'm trying to see if an event is fired when a user ends the conversation prematurely, e.g. closing a web chat window? Is there a way of listening for this kind of behaviour and acting upon it?

Answer (score 0):

according to [this doc](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.iconversationupdate.html)  there is a membersRemoved in the IconversationUpdated interface.  You should be able to use that to capture a user leaving event.

Comment: No such luck with bot-emulator, I'm afraid. I'm currently using middleware to expire the session after 10 minutes of inactivity.